# How to detect an error in a compiled application? (Android Studio 3+)

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible in android studio to see the system or non-system log if the device is not with me? That is, if I could connect to it via usb, then everything would be simple, but we do not have such an opportunity. At the moment I was getting along with the try {} catch {} construct, but now I ran into a problem that I can’t detect an error in the code, although I’ve put it on everywhere like try {} catch {}. Maybe there are some libraries or even the ability to track the log in the compiled application? Or maybe you can somehow connect other than to your tablet and make a debbug this way? For example, on the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Google's Fabric Crashlytics, go to this link for more description

link [fabric](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this will help us!

Comment: happy coding :-)